# iOS WKWebView load html contain Audio, the audio can't autoplay

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview, autoplay

I am using Xamarin to customize an iOS WKWebView to load an HTML file. This HTML file contains an autoplaying audio file, but no matter what I try, the audio does not autoplay once the HTML has loaded. I have already set the code to allow for autoplay of the HTML.

```
defaultConfig.Preferences.SetValueForKey(FromObject(true), new NSString("allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"));
                defaultConfig.SetValueForKey(FromObject(true), new NSString("allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"));
                defaultConfig.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
                defaultConfig.MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.None;
                defaultConfig.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;

 LoadFileUrl(new NSUrl(playerPath, false), new NSUrl(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), true));
```

this my test html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>music</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <embed src="1201111234.mp3" title="ceshi2" loop="false" controls = "false" autostart="true"/> -->
    <audio src="1201111234.mp3" autoplay = "true"> </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you add the following permission in info.plist file: `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>`

Comment: You can use Safari tools to debug the html and check if the mp3 file is loaded correctly in the html. Refer to apple documentation: [Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW8:~:text=com.bundle.identifier-,Safari%20on%20iOS,-You%20can%20use).